# IE8 Self-Closing HTML5 Tags

Tags: html, internet-explorer, respond.js

I'm using respond.js to get IE8 and under to recognize my media queries. This was working just fine for a long time but now IE8 seems to be self-closing any HTML5 tags. Wether respond.js is being called or not.

So I'm getting things like:

```
<article class="foo"/>
...
</article/>
```

I'm testing using F12 tools in IE10.

Comment: Do you have a link or a demo?  Have you added `display:block` for all the html5 elements to your css?  Are you using an html5shiv/shim?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an outdated Drupal module. The version of libraries we were running wasn't compatible with the modernizr module.